# Can't load javascript in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a javascript file but it doesn't work.

My code :

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://mywebsite.com/file.js\"></script></body></html>"];
[_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

This code is supposed to display a video, but nothing happens.
This code displays correctly the video in Desktop browser, my JS is correct.

Comment: Why are you using html description ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use url in baseURL

```
NSURL *base=[NSURL URLWithString:@"website.com"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use string description. Instead use:

```
      [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write following code in `- webViewDidFinishLoad:`

```
NSString * strJavaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com/file.js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:strJavaScript];
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your JS

Comment: It loads an IFrame of a partenaire's website and appends it in the body. There is a video player inside.